# Enabling/disablin(show/Hide) Table Columns using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with jquery inorder to hide and to show certain columns in Mvc view page. The below code is used by me inorder to hide and show the columns.using this i cannot show the column which is hided once.

```
$(".th_1 ").hide(),
$(".th_1 ").show()
```

I am quite newbie to Jquery, Any insight would be great help

Comment: i think you just need to use .toggle() it will auto show or hide.

Comment: better you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toggle()` for hide/show

```
      $(".th_1").toggle();
```

or `slideToggle()` for smooth transition,

```
      $(".th_1").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead.